# pdfLaTeX seems to stop during compiling

Tags: errors, pdftex, compiling

I'm using TeXmaker ant TeX live.
When I try to compile my document it compiles forever until I abort it. The log just ends in the middle of a command or word and gives no error message. The same problem appears on my roommate's PC but not on another PC in another network. Can anyone help me?

Here's the log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.10.6)  6 OCT 2020 14:01
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01>
L3 programming layer <2020-09-24> xparse <2020-03-03>
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script document class (book)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
Package: scrkbase 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
Package: scrbase 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty
Package: scrlfile-hook 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \BeforeFile with sig. 'm' on line 61.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterFile with sig. 'm' on line 65.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \BeforeClass with sig. 'm' on line 69.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \BeforePackage with sig. 'm' on line 73.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterAtEndOfClass with sig. 'smo+m' on line 83.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterAtEndOfPackage with sig. 'smo+m' on line
(LaTeX3)     93.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \scrlfile@AfterClass with sig. 'smo+m' on line
(LaTeX3)     173.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterClass with sig. '' on line 174.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \scrlfile@AfterPackage with sig. 'smo+m' on line
(LaTeX3)     191.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterPackage with sig. '' on line 192.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \ReplaceInput with sig. '' on line 193.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \ReplaceClass with sig. 'mm' on line 196.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \ReplacePackage with sig. 'mm' on line 199.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \UnReplaceInput with sig. '' on line 200.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \UnReplaceClass with sig. 'm' on line 203.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \UnReplacePackage with sig. 'mm' on line 206.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \PreventPackageFromLoading with sig. 's+om' on
(LaTeX3)     line 234.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \StorePreventPackageFromLoading with sig. 'm' on
(LaTeX3)     line 242.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \ResetPreventPackageFromLoading with sig. '' on
(LaTeX3)     line 247.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \UnPreventPackageFromLoading with sig. 'sm' on
(LaTeX3)     line 261.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \BeforeClosingMainAux with sig. 'om' on line
(LaTeX3)     274.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AfterReadingMainAux with sig. 'om' on line 287.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \protected@immediate@write with sig. 'm+m+m' on
(LaTeX3)     line 298.


(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty
Package: scrlogo 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (logo)
)))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty
Package: tocbasic 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip47
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box47
)
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `toc' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 137.
Package scrbook Info: You've used standard option `11pt'.
(scrbook)             This is correct!
(scrbook)             Internally I'm using `fontsize=11pt'.
(scrbook)             If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(scrbook)             you'd have to use `fontsize=11pt' there
(scrbook)             instead of `11pt', too.
Class scrbook Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used to setup font sizes on input li
ne 2437.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt
)
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package: typearea 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip48
\ta@div=\count175
\ta@hblk=\skip49
\ta@vblk=\skip50
\ta@temp=\skip51
\footheight=\skip52
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 47.2316pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = -12.5192pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1740.
)
\c@part=\count176
\c@chapter=\count177
\c@section=\count178
\c@subsection=\count179
\c@subsubsection=\count180
\c@paragraph=\count181
\c@subparagraph=\count182
\scr@dte@chapter@maxnumwidth=\skip53
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\chapter on input line 5625.
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip54
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\section on input line 5636.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\section on input line 5636.
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip55
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=true'
(scrbook)           for `\part on input line 5645.
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip56
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsection on input line 5655.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsection on input line 5655.
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip57
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5665.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subsubsection on input line 5665.
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip58
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\paragraph on input line 5676.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\paragraph on input line 5676.
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip59
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subparagraph on input line 5686.
Class scrbook Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrbook)           for `\subparagraph on input line 5686.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip60
\belowcaptionskip=\skip61
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box48
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `lof' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 6929.

\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip62
\c@figure=\count183
Package tocbasic Info: babel extension for `lot' omitted
(tocbasic)             because of missing \bbl@set@language on input line 6950.

\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip63
\c@table=\count184
Class scrbook Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 7123.
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count185
\Gm@cntv=\count186
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count187
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen139
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen140
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen141
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen142
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen143
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen144
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen145
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen146
\Gm@dimlist=\toks16
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty
Package: setspace 2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2020/08/01 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks17
\inpenc@posthook=\toks18
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2020/10/03 3.49 The Babel package

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2020/10/03 3.49 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count188
\U@D=\dimen147
\l@babelnohyphens=\language86

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@readstream=\read2
)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count189

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngerman.ldf
Language: ngerman 2020/07/21 v2.12 German support for babel (post-1996 orthogra
phy)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngermanb.ldf
Language: ngermanb 2020/07/21 v2.12 German support for babel (post-1996 orthogr
aphy)
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 121.
))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/german.ldf
Language: german 2020/07/21 v2.12 German support for babel (pre-1996 orthograph
y)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/germanb.ldf
Language: germanb 2020/07/21 v2.12 German support for babel (pre-1996 orthograp
hy)
)))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/libertine.sty
Package: libertine 2020/03/26 (Bob Tennent) Supports Libertine and Biolinum fon
ts for all LaTeX engines.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks19
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks20
)
\XKV@depth=\count190
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+lmr on input line 11
2.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.sty
Package: fontaxes 2020/07/21 v1.0e Font selection axes
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 29.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 33.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \swshape on input line 35.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 37.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sscshape on input line 39.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ulcshape on input line 41.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsw on input line 47.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textssc on input line 48.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textulc on input line 49.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 484.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/LinLibertine_I.tex))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
Package: caption 2020/09/12 v3.5b Customizing captions (AR)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
Package: caption3 2020/09/17 v2.1b caption3 kernel (AR)
\captionmargin=\dimen148
\captionmargin@=\dimen149
\captionwidth=\dimen150
\caption@tempdima=\dimen151
\caption@indent=\dimen152
\caption@parindent=\dimen153
\caption@hangindent=\dimen154
Package caption Info: KOMA-Script document class detected.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption-koma.sto
File: caption-koma.sto 2020/09/12 v2.0a Adaption of the caption package to the 
KOMA-Script document classes (AR)
))
Package caption Info: Option `tablename' requires the `newfloat' package on inp
ut line 174.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newfloat/newfloat.sty
Package: newfloat 2019/09/02 v1.1l Defining new floating environments (AR)
)
\c@caption@flags=\count191
\c@continuedfloat=\count192
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
Package: csquotes 2019-12-06 v5.2j context-sensitive quotations (JAW)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/08/24 v2.5j e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count193
)
\csq@reset=\count194
\csq@gtype=\count195
\csq@glevel=\count196
\csq@qlevel=\count197
\csq@maxlvl=\count198
\csq@tshold=\count199
\csq@ltx@everypar=\toks21

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def
File: csquotes.def 2019-12-06 v5.2j csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
)
Package csquotes Info: Trying to load configuration file 'csquotes.cfg'...
Package csquotes Info: ... configuration file loaded successfully.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg
File: csquotes.cfg 
))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/blindtext/blindtext.sty
Package: blindtext 2012/01/06 V2.0 blindtext-Package

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty
Package: xspace 2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
)
\c@blindtext=\count266
\c@Blindtext=\count267
\c@blind@countparstart=\count268
\blind@countxx=\count269
\blindtext@numBlindtext=\count270
\blind@countyy=\count271
\c@blindlist=\count272
\c@blindlistlevel=\count273
\c@blindlist@level=\count274
\blind@listitem=\count275
\c@blind@listcount=\count276
\c@blind@levelcount=\count277
\blind@mathformula=\count278
\blind@Mathformula=\count279
\c@blind@randomcount=\count280
\c@blind@randommax=\count281
\c@blind@pangramcount=\count282
\c@blind@pangrammax=\count283
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pslatex/pslatex.sty
Package: pslatex 1996/07/24 v1.2 pslatex emulation (DPC)
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/lmr/m/n --> OT1/ptmcm/m/n on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/lmr/bx/n --> OT1/ptmcm/m/n on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `letters' on input line 66.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/lmm/m/it --> OML/ptmcm/m/it on input line 66.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/lmm/b/it --> OML/ptmcm/m/it on input line 66.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `symbols' on input line 67.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/lmsy/m/n --> OMS/pzccm/m/n on input line 67.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/lmsy/b/n --> OMS/pzccm/m/n on input line 67.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `largesymbols' on input line 68.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/lmex/m/n --> OMX/psycm/m/n on input line 68.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/lmex/m/n --> OMX/psycm/m/n on input line 68.
\symbold=\mathgroup4
\symitalic=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 74.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/lmr/bx/n --> OT1/ptm/bx/n on input line 74.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/lmr/bx/n --> OT1/ptm/bx/n on input line 74.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathit on input line 75.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/lmr/m/it --> OT1/ptm/m/it on input line 75.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/lmr/bx/it --> OT1/ptm/m/it on input line 75.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 226.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 230.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 234.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 243.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 384.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 388.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 392.


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 401.

) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chemcompounds/chemcompounds.sty
Package: chemcompounds 2006/12/01 v1.1.3 Dictionary for compound numbering
\c@chemcompounds@counter=\count284
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psfrag/psfrag.sty
Package: psfrag 1998/04/11 v3.04 PSfrag (MCG)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/08/26 v1.2 Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\pfg@pcount=\count285
\pfg@scount=\count286
\pfg@temp=\write3
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bpchem/bpchem.sty
Package: bpchem 2004/08/21 v1.1 Chemical input helper
\BPClensub=\skip64
\BPClensuper=\skip65
\BPCdelta=\skip66
LaTeX Info: Redefining \allowhyphens on input line 122.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \| on input line 138.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \- on input line 146.
\c@BPCno=\count287
\c@BPCnoa=\count288
Package bpchem Info: using default math greek fonts on input line 213.
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chemnum/chemnum.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2020-09-24 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2020-09-24 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count289
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box49
))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2020-05-15 L3 Experimental document command parser

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.tex))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
Package: l3keys2e 2020-05-15 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
Package: chemnum 2019/10/02 v1.2c a comprehensive approach for the numbering of
 chemical compounds (CN)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations.sty
Package: translations 2020/04/28 v1.8b internationalization of LaTeX2e packages
 (CN)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chemgreek/chemgreek.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks22
\ex@=\dimen155
))
Package: chemgreek 2020/01/16 v1.1a interface for upright Greek letters for use
 in chemistry (CN)
\l__chemgreek_tmpa_int=\count290
\g__chemgreek_tmpa_int=\count291
)
\l__chemnum_tmpa_int=\count292
\l__chemnum_tmpb_int=\count293
\l__chemnum_tmpc_int=\count294
\c@cmpdmain=\count295
\g__chemnum_main_int=\count296
\l__chemnum_compound_replace_int=\count297
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auto-pst-pdf/auto-pst-pdf.sty
Package: auto-pst-pdf 2009/04/26 v0.6 Wrapper for pst-pdf

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
Package: ifplatform 2017/10/13 v0.4a Testing for the operating system

(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/
```

and the preamble:

```latex
\documentclass[ ngerman,11pt,
                paper=a4,
                listsfo=totoc,
                bibliography=totocnumbered,
                parskip=half,
                twoside=true,
                ]{scrbook}

\usepackage[inner=3.5cm,
outer=2.5cm,
top=2cm,
bottom=2cm,
includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}           
\usepackage{lmodern}        
\usepackage{libertine}       
\usepackage{enumerate}


\usepackage[tablename=Tab.]{caption}
\usepackage[figurename=Abb.]{caption}
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption} 
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\usepackage{csquotes,        
    amsmath,        
    amsfonts,       
    amssymb,        
    siunitx,        
    xcolor,         
    tabularx,       
    booktabs,       
    caption,        
    graphicx,        
    wrapfig,         
    blindtext,
    pslatex 
}
\usepackage{chemcompounds} 
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\newcommand{\CNfig}[1]{\sffamily{\CNref{#1}}}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}
\usepackage{chemgreek}
\usepackage[runs=2, crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage[backend=biber,      
            style=chem-angew,
            sorting=none,       
            bibwarn=true,       
            bibencoding=utf8    
            ]{biblatex}         
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}

\newcommand{\hcite}[1]{\textsuperscript{\cite{#1}}}
\usepackage[headsepline=1pt,footsepline=0.4pt,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}
\ihead[]{}
\chead[]{}
\ohead[\headmark]{\headmark}
\ifoot[]{}
\cfoot[]{}

\usepackage[intoc, german]{nomencl}

\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\let\abk\nomenclature
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.50 \hsize}
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}
\newcommand{\ncl}[3][\empty]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\empty}}
        {\nomenclature{\textbf{#2}}{#3}}
        {\nomenclature[#1]{\textbf{#2}}{#3}}}
\makenomenclature
```

Comment: show the code you are trying to compile, (probably only the preamble matter and you can replace the body, by hello world).

Comment: I added it now above

Comment: I guess it's a problem with shell-escape or the pslatex or auto-pst-pdf package

Comment: well start to remove packages from your preamble until you get something with a manageable size to demonstrate the error.

Comment: without auto-pst-pdf it works. But I need this package for enbedding eps-files

Comment: debugging auto-pst-pdf is a quite a pain, so if you want help please clean up your preamble from all the unrelated stuff, and show then the shorter log-file.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I now try pstool instead of auto-pst-pdf. I hope it works

Comment: I recommend urgently not to use auto-pst-pdf for now, it just tried to delete my whole test folder.

Comment: Do you know an alternative? I use auto-pst-pdf in combination with chemnum to replace tags in eps-files

Comment: I assume that it stopped to work for you because windows is waiting that you answer the security question I got on the command line. You will have to wait a bit, I wrote the auto-pst-pdf maintainer about it.

Comment: I waited hours and nothing happened. What is the auto-pst-pdf maintainer?

Comment: I meant you will have to wait until auto-pst-pdf is updated. You can try to disable the cleanup: `\usepackage[runs=2, crop=off,cleanup=]{auto-pst-pdf}`

Comment: due to the author it won't be updated

Comment: I will convince him, don't worry.

Comment: okay, thank you :D the cleanup-option worked, but now I have a ghostscript-error: GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Comment: A new auto-pst-pdf is already on the to ctan. For your Ghostscript error open a new question with a *small* example.